# Max item quantity added to cart based on product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, categories

I am trying to customize the shop such that Category named Quantity4 allows only 4 items to be added in the cart and category named Quantity6 allows only items to be added in the cart.

As far as I can get, this can be achieved using nested `if` statements, but somehow this doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'only_four_items_allowed_add_to_cart', 10, 3 );

function only_four_items_allowed_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {

$cart_items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
$total_count = $cart_items_count + $quantity;

if(has_term('quantity4','product_cat',$product_id )){
if($cart_items_count >= 4 || $total_count > 4){
        // Set to false
        $passed = false;
        // Display a message
        wc_add_notice( __( "You Chose a Box of 4 Items, Can't Add More", "woocommerce" ), "error" );
    }
  }

  else if (has_term('quantity6','product_cat',$product_id )){
    if($cart_items_count >= 6 || $total_count > 6){
        // Set to false
        $passed = false;
        // Display a message
        wc_add_notice( __( "You Chose a Box of 6 Items, Can't Add More", "woocommerce" ), "error" );
    }
}

return $passed;
}
```

Can someone pls point out what am I doing wrong here and how to get the desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have revisited your code a bit and it's working. Please try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'only_four_items_allowed_add_to_cart', 10, 3 );
function only_four_items_allowed_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $total_count = $cart_count + $quantity;

    if ( has_term( 'quantity4','product_cat',$product_id ) && ( $cart_count >= 4 || $total_count > 4 ) ) {
        $passed = false; // Set to false
        $notice = __( "You Chose a Box of 4 Items, Can't Add More", "woocommerce" ); // Notice to display
    }
    elseif ( has_term( 'quantity6','product_cat',$product_id ) && ( $cart_count >= 6 || $total_count > 6 ) ) {
        $passed = false; // Set to false
        $notice = __( "You Chose a Box of 6 Items, Can't Add More", "woocommerce" ); // Notice to display
    }
    if( ! $passed )
        wc_add_notice( $notice, 'error' );

    return $passed;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks! Buddy Perfect, But when going to cart page that time update adds 4 or more product add-in quantity box then update cart so the cart is updated. @SwapnaLekshmanan

Comment: @SavanDholu Ask a new question then… and please could you clean (remove) those comments here (thank you)…